# Disable Button When Deleting in Redux and React

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, material-ui, redux-thunk

I have here a problem disabling the button when deleting.
Right now, it disables all the "Delete" Button of all images.
I only wanted to disable the "Delete" of the currently deleting image.|
So it it will prevent from deleting it again and again while it is still processing.

Codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-upload-images-forked-e5t7l3?file=/src/components/ProductCard/index.js)

```
<CardActions>
    <Button
      disabled={isDeletingImages}
      variant="contained"
      size="medium"
      color="primary"
      type="button"
      onClick={() => confirmDeleteProductImage(productType?.imageFileName)}
    >
      Delete
    </Button>
  </CardActions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single `isDeletingImages` boolean state that you are using for all delete button's `disabled` prop.

I suggest converting to a Map/Object of ids that are currently being deleted, and checking by id if the delete button for the currently rendered item is currently being deleted.

1. Update the `deleteProductImage` action creator to dispatch the `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REQUEST` and `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FAILURE` action types with the current `imageFileName` as `payload`.

   ```
   export const deleteProductImage = ({
     productIndex,
     imageFileName,
     callback = () => {}
   }) => async (dispatch) => {
     try {
       dispatch({
         type: appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REQUEST,
         payload: { productIndex, imageFileName }, // <-- pass payload
       });

       const response = await axios.get(
         "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
       );

       if (response) {
         dispatch({
           type: appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
           payload: { productIndex, imageFileName }
         });
       }
     } catch (error) {
       dispatch({
         type: appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FAILURE,
         payload: { productIndex, imageFileName }, // <-- pass payload
       });
     }
   };
   ```
2. Update the `productReducer` to use an object instead of a boolean value.

   ```
   export const initialState = {
     products: [],
     errors: [],
     isDeletingImages: {} // <-- object to hold file names
   };
   ```
3. Update the `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REQUEST`, `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS`, and `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FAILURE` reducer cases to set/clear the current delete status by the file name.

   ```
   case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REQUEST:
     return {
       ...state,
       isDeletingImages: {
         ...state.isDeletingImages,
         [action.payload.imageFileName]: true
       }
     };

   case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
     return {
       ...state,
       isDeletingImages: {
         ...state.isDeletingImages,
         [action.payload.imageFileName]: false
       },
       products: state?.products.map((item, index) => {
         if (index !== action.payload?.productIndex) return item;

         return {
           ...item,
           productImages: item?.productImages.filter(
             ({ imageFileName = null }) =>
               imageFileName !== action?.payload?.imageFileName
           )
         };
       })
     };

   case appConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FAILURE:
     return {
       ...state,
       isDeletingImages: {
         ...state.isDeletingImages,
         [action.payload.imageFileName]: false
       }
     };
   ```
4. Update the delete button to check the `isDeletingImages` state with its current `imageFileName` value.

   ```
   <Button
     disabled={isDeletingImages[productType.imageFileName]}
     variant="contained"
     size="medium"
     color="primary"
     type="button"
     onClick={() => confirmDeleteProductImage(productType?.imageFileName)}
   >
     Delete
   </Button>
   ```

[image: Edit disable-button-when-deleting-in-redux-and-react]

Answer (score 0):

When `DELETE_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REQUEST` is being dispatched, you could add the image file name as additional payload to the action (I'm assuming that the file name uniquely identifies the thing that is being deleted).

In the reducer, read the image file name from the action payload and mutate the state so that it reflects which specific images are in the process of being deleted. For example with an object that contains the image file name as a key and `true` as value.

```
export const initialState = {
  products: [],
  errors: [],
  imagesInDeletion: {
    // example entry: 'nameofimage.jpg': true,
  },
};
```

`imagesInDeletion` now tells you which image is in the process of being deleted. You can write a selector based on it, something like `isImageBeingDeleted('nameofimage.jpg')` and let it return `true` or `false`. The selector can then be used for the `disabled` prop of the button.

In addition there'd be some work to do in the reducer to update this state properly. If an image was successfully deleted, it should be removed from `imagesInDeletion`, for example.

This is one possible way of solving this, but the core of the problem is that you need a more detailed state for each product/image that tracks the lifecycle of image deletion. Sometimes re-modelling the state to facilitate that can also be a good approach.